# How do i get the names and capabilities of the print queues installed using UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm new to UWP so please bear with me.
Is there any way that i can enumerate the list of printers installed in a system and the capabilities like the paper sizes supported or the connection type(Network/USB/Local port) using a UWP application.

In WPF i guess you can use System.Printing namespace to recieve this information, but i'm not able to find the same in UWP.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices It looks as if they moved it to a new namespace `Windows.Devices.Enumeration` so might want to check there?

Comment: Microsoft Has PrintHelper that will do all this for you without even writing single line of code. I would suggest you not to spend time in reinventing the wheel but rather check [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) and use the same.